# Difference in client/server JVM options

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

In the Java Hotspot compiler, what the difference between initializing Java with `-client` as opposed to `-server`, and what are the pros/cons/caveats of each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice information can be found in [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/performance/hotspot.html) and [Java Hotspot VM FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_types). Acording to them, a **Java HotSpot Server VM**:

- Is intended for running server applications.
- Prefers to maximize operating speed instead of minimizing start-up time.

On the other side, a **Java HotSpot Client VM**:

- Is better suited for GUI applications
- Is intended to provide fast start-up times or small footprints.

Comment: Also check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html the "tiered compilation" paragraph.